# Gnome-shell and removal devices

Tags: mount, gnome, fstab

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 with Gnome-shell. In /etc/fstab i add following lines:

```
/dev/sda4                     /media/D        ntfs    none       0       1
```

When i move mouse on right bottom corner i see indicator - removable device. In this indicator i see only my real hard drive (ntfs volume). Can i remove this icon for hard drive, but stay work for removable devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mount your drive at `/mnt/D` instead of `/media/D` by altering `/etc/fstab` and you should not see it any more.